# Как обратиться к значению JSON

Tags: php, массивы, json

После json_decode имею вот такое массив. Как обратиться по ключу и получить значение?

```html
stdClass Object
(
    [$] => on
)
```

Comment: `$data->{'$'}` ?

Comment: Спасибо! Это верный ответ!

Comment: запостил ответом

Answer (score 2):

Для доступа к полям объектов, которые в названии имеют пробелы, дефисы и т.п. символы не удовлетворяющие правилами именования переменных и полей используется синтаксис `$object->{'my-field name'}`:

```
$json = '{ "$": 123, "test": 2343 }';
$data = json_decode($json);

print_r([ $data->{'$'} ]);
```